Joint measurability of a function in $C(0,T;L^1(\mathbb{R}))$
Let $f \in C(0,T;L^1(\mathbb{R}))$, meaning that for each $t \in (0,T)$, $f(t, \cdot) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and the map $t \mapsto f(t, \cdot)$ is continuous with respect to the $L^1$-norm.
Does this imply that $f(t, x)$ is jointly measurable as a function on $(0,T) \times \mathbb{R}$?
Additionally, in general, what are the sufficient conditions (in addition to separate measurability) that ensure a function is jointly measurable on a product space  $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated!

Under the assumption of the continuum hypothesis, there is an old counterexample due to Sierpinski. I don't know if there is a ZFC-friendly counterexample though…

A lot of similar problems were studied by Chernivtsi school of analysis, so I suggest to ask people from here. For instance, Olena Karlova,
Volodymyr Mykhaylyuk,
and Oleksandr V. Maslyuchenko.
So I suggest you to write to them a letter about your problem with regards from me.
